# How do I solve time format VBA overflow error?

Tags: vba, overflow

I'm using a userform to schedule a task. In that userform, I have two **Combo Boxes** to select:

- The time it should be scheduled.
- The duration of the task.

For those two fields I use following code:

```
Option Explicit 

Private Sub ScDuration_Change()   
   ScDuration = Format(ScDuration, "hh:mm")
End Sub

Private Sub ScDuration_AfterUpdate()
   ScDuration = Format(ScDuration, "hh:mm")
End Sub

Private Sub ScTime_Change()
   ScTime = Format(ScTime, "hh:mm")
End Sub

Private Sub ScTime_AfterUpdate()
   ScTime = Format(ScTime, "hh:mm")
End Sub
```

But this is giving me an overflow error `Run-time error '6': Overflow` for which I already spent hours trying to fix. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Durations are not units of time, even tho they are similar. A time unit can have only 23 hours 59 minutes and 59 seconds (and a fraction of seconds) so durations should be stored as something like "number of seconds" (depending on your needs) instead in a different type of variable, like `Long`

Comment: Your code and question make no sense - you are setting the value of the controls to the value of themselves, and you don't indicate where the overflow occurs. You can easily and directly add a duration to a time, but your published code doesn't attempt that.

Comment: You could try something like: `Format(Timeserial(0,ScDuration,0), "hh:mm")` since I'm assuming the amount of minutes will be entered instead of an actual time format. I think it's up to 1440 where it clocks over past midnight and will start from 00:00 again. For example if `ScDuration = 1439` then after the format it will show `23:59`. If you dont want 24 hour clock then add `am/pm` to the end of format (`"hh:mm am/pm"`) and it will show `11:59 pm`.

Comment: @Gustav The "Duration" `ScDuration` and the "Scheduled Time" `ScTime`, are chosen from a list via a combobox on a userform. They are already formatted as time in Excel. As soon as I choose one of the times in that list, which will trigger the "_AfterUpdate"-Sub, it causes the Overflow error.

Comment: But you are setting the value to itself: `ScDuration = Format(ScDuration, "hh:mm")` . It doesn't make sense. And there is no "cell" in the code, so where is that done? Also, if the content of these cells are true time values (applied a format), why using `Format` at all? The "cells" should be assigned a true time value, not a string from `Format`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solve your problem or at least help you

Be patient and change all your need to adapt it to your code

Good Luck!

'Here begin the code, all inside the form code

```
Private GLOBAL_DATE As Double
Private GLOBAL_DURATION As Double ' I didnt use it but could be used
Private GLOBAL_UOM_TIME As Double
Private Const FORMAT_DATE_DISPLAY = "DD-MM-YYYY"

'Label1 = time
'Label2 = duration
'Define max valuee for duration in minutes, hours, seconds
'Define max vaule of your dateSpinner 
'in minutes divide 1440
'hours divide 24
'seconds 86400


Sub Global_initiation()
    GLOBAL_DATE = CDbl(Now)
    GLOBAL_DURATION = 0
    GLOBAL_UOM_TIME = 1440
    
End Sub


'You will recibe the value of spiner
Function HandleMinutes(nMinutes_ As Double) As String
    HandleMinutes = Format(nMinutes_ / GLOBAL_UOM_TIME, "hh:mm")
End Function

Function HandleDate(nDays_ As Double) As String
    HandleDate = Format(GLOBAL_DATE + nDays_, FORMAT_DATE_DISPLAY)
End Function



Private Sub SpinButton1_Change() ' date
    Label1.Caption = HandleDate(SpinButton1.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton2_Change() ' duration
    Label2.Caption = HandleMinutes(SpinButton2.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Global_initiation
End Sub
```

'Here ends the code--------------------

[image: Form]

[image: Running]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
ScTime.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(ScTime.Value, "h:mm")

Considering the comments in the Randy's video bellow, it seems that one some machines "Format" may not work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h79SNTpxKzc